# Having one or more Java-Modules, shared with multiple Spring-boot-projects

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven, sharing, java-module

I have the following in my eclipse Workspace: (JDK-11, Maven):
**1)** Two spring-boot projects
(A) Proj-SB-1    (B) Proj-SB-2

**2)** Two java-modules, each having their own POM.xml 
(A) JM1  (B)JM2

**Question**:
Please recommended a way, to share JM1 with both Proj-SB-1 and Proj-SB-2.
Some sites say that JM1 and JM2 poms should mention the parent-pom-project.
**Issue** with that is, JM1 will then limit itself to only Proj-SB-1 OR Proj-SB-2, but not both. Hence sharing wont be possible.
Please let me know if there is a way to achieve sharing.
thanks
-Prashant

Comment: What do you mean by "sharing"? If one project should use another, you can declare a `<dependency>`.

Comment: 'Shared' may not be the correct word, but to explain myself.... For example,  like a jar file can be used by two different spring-boot projects(apps),  can I have a java-module,  used/included by two different spring-boot projects(apps) ?